# sending data from js to the mvc controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have on the view list of images with checkbox in front each image. Checkbox is populated with image id so I can recognize which image is checked for manipulation.

When button is clicked I'm recognizing which images are checked and store each image id to the array of ints. These array I want to sent to the mvc3 controller but I have problem I'm getting error inside sent parameters (firebug). For example if two images are checked I got following:

```
undefined   undefined
undefined   undefined
```

here's the code

```
var imgList = [];
$('#deleteImgBtn').click(function () {
    $('.imgCheckbox:checked').each(function () {      
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        imgList.push(id);
    });
    jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;   
    $.ajax({
        url: '/property/deleteimages',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  imgList ,
        success: function(result){
            alert("ok");
        }
    });
...


public ActionResult DeleteImages(int[] data)
        {
            return PartialView(data);            
        }
```

Comment: How does your markup look like? How does the controller action you are posting to look like? There's not enough information in this question to be answered and it might be soon closed.

Comment: I'm getting null at the controller action parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Property/DeleteImages',
    type: 'POST',
    data:  { data : imgList },
    traditional : true,
    success: function(result){
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```